# Mysql Populating dropdown based on another dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I've been testing out a lot of codes for this but i can't get it to work.
I want to populate a dropdown based on the value of another dropdown.
EDIT:
my table name is zipcode and i have CITY, STATE, Zipcode, FULLSTATE, and zipID
STATE is abbreviation of FULLSTATE

I have:
zipcode:php

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Zipcode Help */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM zipcode group by FULLSTATE";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$dd .= "<option value='".$row['STATE']."'>".$row['FULLSTATE']."</option>";
} 
?>
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1" onchange="populatelist">
<option value="empty" selected>--Select State--</option>
<?php echo $dd; ?>
</select>
<select id="city" name="city">
<option value="empty">&nbsp;</option>
</select>
<!--content of the page-->
<div class="container-wrapper clearfix" id="main-content-container">
<div class="container">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
</div> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Jquery:

```
function populatelist()
{
var qry=document.getelementbyid('dropdown1').value;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
{
});
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "help.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("qry="+qry);
}
```

Reference Page:(help.php)

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Help */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$value=$_POST['qry'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM zipcode where STATE like '$value'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$ee .= "<option value='".$row['CITY']."'>".$row['CITY']."</option>";
}     
echo $ee;
mysql_close();
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Questions: Where should i put my help.php if i'm using wordpress?
I've created a custom template named 'help' then created a page in dashboard and assigned that template. Is this correct? I uploaded it on the theme directory. Also put it inside the js folder. I dunno I never tried jquery before :S

How should i call the jquery?
I put it on header:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
    <?php wp_head() ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/js/zipcode.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've been doing this for 3 days already and i'm so exhausted. I really don't know where to put the reference page

Comment: You don't need a second query. And GROUP BY is liable to give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your `zipcode.php` file.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Zipcode Help */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM zipcode group by FULLSTATE";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $dd .= "<option value='".$row['STATE']."'>".$row['FULLSTATE']."</option>";
} 
?>
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
  <option value="empty" selected>--Select State--</option>
<?php echo $dd; ?>
</select>

<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
</select>

<!--content of the page-->
<div class="container-wrapper clearfix" id="main-content-container">
<div class="container">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () { 

    $('#dropdown1').change(function () {

        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == "") {

            $("#city").html("<option value=''>Select</option>");

        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>helper/help.php",
                data: "value=" + value,
                success: function (server_response) {

                    $("#city").html(server_response);

                }

            }); //$.ajax ends here

        } //if else     
        return false
    });

}); // function ends here
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Inside your wordpress theme folder create a folder called helper and put your helper.php file in there.

Use the following code in your help.php file;

```
<?php

$value = $_POST['value'];

global $wpdb;
$value= a_href;
$query = "SELECT * FROM zipcode where STATE like '$value'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $ee .= "<option value='".$row['CITY']."'>".$row['CITY']."</option>";
}       
echo $ee ;      
                     
?>
```

I didn't test the code but I think it should work. Let me know if you have any more question.

**Make sure Jquery is loaded properly

**Very Important**:  `mysql_query` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 . You should use PDO or mysqli extension. Check This:  https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: so the script will be added in zipcode.php which also contains my html form? leaving me with only 2 files (zipcode.php - form + script) and (help.php - put in helper folder)

Comment: also, should i delete the dropdown1 onchange? if no, should i add populatelist inside the $(function ()?

still can't get it to work. I've added the js inside zipcode.php just after the <?php get_header(); ?> part

also added </script> to close the script

Comment: Yes the JS script should be added in the `zipcode.php` file where you have the form and the php code should be in the helper.php. You have to get rid of the `onchange="populatelist"`from your form and also the js function. Check my updated code above